# A lot of helper methods are needed to assist in my unit test class - is this normal?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I have a class which installs software drivers via WMI. However, I've noticed that in writing my unit tests, to perform the assert, I need additional helper methods. E.g. to ensure that the driver's added, I need to make sure that the count of drivers has gone up by one, which is not a method in the class-under-test.

Is this normal for unit tests, or am I doing something wrong? I am just going to take all these helper methods and extract them to a static class.

Thanks

Comment: imho: Your tests should be testing the exposed functionality of the thing being tested. It seems like it might be getting to semantics if the code to count the drivers before and after is located in `WmiDriverInstallerHelper` or inside your test fixture class. But you shouldn't be modifying your public interface to suit testing. i would leave the method where it is but make it protected, and *friend* your test fixture to the class you're testing so you can call the protected method.

Comment: If your tests modify the state of the operating system (by installing software or even requiring a reboot as part of the test process), my suggestion is to consider using virtual machine and automation tools designed for integration / end-to-end testing. Each run should start with a known clean condition (or known dirty condition, if there is a way to re-create the exact same condition.) Running these heavy tests inside a unit test harness isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you're doing an *integration test* rather than a unit test, as it looks like you're using the real dependencies of the class under test (the installer class). In a unit test, you would inject mock or stubs to simulate the dependencies.

Integration tests usually require more setup that unit tests, as they need to

- Setup and **assert** a any preconditions, e.g. that the driver is not installed before running the test. Unit Tests don't need to test preconditions, except on rare occasions.
- Run the feature under test, e.g. the installation.
- Assert any postcondition, e.g. driver number + 1, etc.

### Edit

I'll give you my definition of unit, integration and end-to-end test as it might vary from someone else definition. Regardless of my definition, testing that you can install your product is a *very* valid test. So the following is just my (potentially wrong) point of view.

#### Unit test

Unit test are completely isolated and can run without any external *dependencies* such as databases, file system, external web services, triggers (such as a cron job), etc. All the peers of the object can be *externalized* (either mocked or stubbed) so the test focuses as much as possible on **only** testing the class under test, and not its dependencies.

#### Integration test

Tests an class that abstract an external resource. For me, integration tests are very much in spirit as unit tests, but require an external (and often slow) resource and might fail because the resource is down.

#### End to end test

Test that exercises a feature using the application interface, configured in a production-like mode. The application interface might be a desktop application, a web UI, webservices, serial port, etc. The key here is that the test covers how all the components interact together (the protocol). These are usually the slowest tests by far.

I have the feeling that you're doing an integration test, as you're only testing a *class* that performs the installation, but it might be an end-to-end test depending which *interface* you're using.

#### An example

Let me give you an example from my current project. One of the features include extracting audio from a video file. To do this, I invoke a command line tool called FFmpeg. In order to be able to test the code, I've separated the code that invokes the command line from the bussiness logic in different classes, in this way I can unit tests the Business logic by passing a mock *AudioExtractor*. Now, the tests of the Audio Extractor are "integration tests" as I'm only testing that class, and that class requiresand external resource the ffmpeg binary to be installed on the computer.

The Audio Extracto test is a bit more complicated, because it has to check that

- Preconditions before running the test:

  - The test video file is present.
  - The audio file doesn't.
  - The binary is installed and is executable.
- Postconditions after the test

  - The audio file was created
  - The audio file is valid
- On the test tear down

  - the audio file has to be deleted.

I do most of those checks via custom [hamcrest](https://github.com/grahamrhay/NHamcrest) matchers (which are helper classes in the end). Oh, and something to keep in mind is that if one of the preconditions fail, it doesn't mean that the code is broken, but that the test cannot run, which is a warning rather than an error.

I think something important is the test should describe the interactions and stay at the right level of abstraction, which probably you're doing by introducing the helpers.

Comment: Indeed, I guess so. Maybe I should look into mocks.

Comment: One other thing - the helper methods I have are put in the unit test, so I'm testing one method in isolation but to assert, I ned extra logic. Is this still an integration-type test?

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: If it is hard to write unit tests, odds are that something is wrong with your design. Like Augusto says, you have probably drifted into the land of integration testing.

Think dependency injection. Each method should do one thing... "do it well, and do it only", as  it says in "Clean Code" by Robert Martin (also known as Uncle Bob).